# Table layout overlaps Linear Layout in Android studio

Tags: android, android-layout

I am having issue aligning my contents in a proper order. When I test my app in emulator, I discovered table layout overlapping the Linear layout. I have tried some solutions but none worked.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:background="@drawable/table_background2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/headerpicture" android:background="@color/loginheader" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
        <TextView android:textSize="20sp" android:textColor="#fff" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp" android:text="@string/fixed_header"/>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imgLeftBack" android:layout_width="35dp" android:layout_height="35dp" android:src="@drawable/arrow_left_green" android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:onClick="goBack" android:contentDescription="@string/empty"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:gravity="center" android:id="@+id/footer" android:background="@color/loginheader" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


        <TextView android:textColor="#fff" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="5dp" android:text="@string/copyright" android:ems="8"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TableLayout android:layout_gravity="top" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:background="@drawable/gradient" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_below="@+id/headerpicture">
        <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:textColor="@color/list_item_text" android:ellipsize="none" android:layout_gravity="top" android:id="@+id/textViewUsernamePicture" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_view_marginLeft" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_view_marginTop" android:text="@string/pre_election_usernameLbl" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" android:id="@+id/txtUsernamePicture" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="@dimen/edit_text_height" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_view_marginLeft" android:ems="8" android:layout_weight="3" android:inputType="text"/>
        </TableRow>
        <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:id="@+id/tableLayout2Row9" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText android:gravity="top|left|center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" android:id="@+id/txtTitle" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"  android:layout_weight="3" android:inputType="text" android:hint="Incident Title" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/table_marginLeft"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
    <ImageView android:layout_marginBottom="0dp" android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/ImgPicture" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_view_marginTop" android:src="@drawable/picture_placeholder" android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout1" android:contentDescription="@string/empty"/>

    <TableLayout android:layout_gravity="top" android:id="@+id/tableLayout2" android:background="@drawable/gradient" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:layout_marginTop="5dp" android:layout_marginRight="5dp" android:layout_below="@+id/ImgPicture">

        <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:id="@+id/tableLayout2Row13" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:textColor="@color/list_item_text" android:ellipsize="none" android:layout_gravity="top" android:id="@+id/textViewPriorityIncident" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_view_marginLeft" android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_view_marginTop" android:text="@string/incident_priorityLbl" android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <Spinner android:entries="@array/incident_priority_arrays" android:id="@+id/spinnerPriorityIncident" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:prompt="@string/incident_priority_prompt"/>
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" android:id="@+id/tableLayout2Row5" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <EditText android:gravity="top|left|center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical|center_horizontal|center" android:id="@+id/txtCommentsIncident" android:scrollbars="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/table_marginLeft" android:lines="4" android:minLines="3" android:ems="8" android:maxLength="@string/comments_length" android:layout_weight="3" android:inputType="textMultiLine" android:hint="Comment"/>

        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/btnsHolder" android:layout_gravity="center" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout2" android:layout_above="@id/footer">
        <Button android:background="@color/red" android:textColor="@color/redtextxolor"  android:tint="@color/redtextxolor" android:id="@+id/btnSaveImage" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/btn_padding_left" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:text="@string/btnBack" android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous" android:onClick="goBack"/>
         <Button  android:background="@color/btn" android:textColor="@color/btntextcolor"  android:tint="@color/btntextcolor"   android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/btnTakePicture" android:paddingLeft="10sp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:text="@string/btnSnap" android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"  android:onClick="captureImage"/>
         <Button  android:background="@color/snap" android:textColor="@color/white"  android:tint="@color/white"   android:layout_gravity="center" android:id="@+id/btnSendPicture" android:paddingLeft="10sp" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_margin="10dp" android:text="@string/btnSendSnap" android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" android:onClick="sendForm"/>

     </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Why do you need the table layout?

Comment: @Merian, because it holds the input fields.

Comment: what should be the position of the spinner in the row? Should it go above the textview?

Comment: @Merian, to be beside it.

Comment: And are the rows one below another?

Comment: @Merian, I have pasted all the codes. Please could you help me go through it?

Comment: I am trying to figure out how the view should be looking and rewrite your code, according to the documentation there are a lot of better containers(more responsive) according to TableView

Comment: If you post image how this should look even if simple paint image would be lot of easier to answer the question

Answer (score 0):

First off that is the worst formatting I have ever seen lol buuut inside the linear layout just set it to be under the table layout

like this

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/mytable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</TableLayout>


<LinearLayout

    android:id="@+id/mylinear"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mytable">
</LinearLayout>
```

notice the android:layout_below="@+id/mytable"> .  which is the id i gave to the table view just do that then they shouldnt overlap, now in your code this would mean you're going to have to give an id to the table layout in order to do this

dont mind the height and width I gave the linear view all you should worry about if the layout_below the rest was just me hitting enter to fill

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:background="@drawable/gradient"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
 android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
 android:layout_marginRight="5dp" >
  <Spinner 
    android:entries="@array/incident_priority_arrays"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerPriorityIncident"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"\ 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:prompt="@string/incident_priority_prompt"/>
 <TextView 
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_text" 
    android:ellipsize="none"
    android:id="@+id/textViewPriorityIncident"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/text_view_marginLeft" 
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/text_view_marginTop" 
    android:text="@string/incident_priorityLbl" />
</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
<EditText 
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:id="@+id/txtCommentsIncident"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/table_marginLeft" 
    android:lines="4" 
    android:minLines="3" 
    android:ems="8" 
    android:maxLength="@string/comments_length" 
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:hint="Comment"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/btnsHolder"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/tableLayout2"
    android:layout_above="@id/footer">
        <Button
        android:background="@color/red"
        android:textColor="@color/redtextxolor" 
        android:tint="@color/redtextxolor" 
        android:id="@+id/btnSaveImage"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/btn_padding_left" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="@string/btnBack"
        android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_media_previous"
        android:onClick="goBack"/>
         <Button 
         android:background="@color/btn"
         android:textColor="@color/btntextcolor"
         android:tint="@color/btntextcolor"
         android:layout_gravity="center" 
         android:id="@+id/btnTakePicture"
         android:paddingLeft="10sp"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:text="@string/btnSnap"
         android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" 
         android:onClick="captureImage"/>
         <Button 
         android:background="@color/snap"
         android:textColor="@color/white"
         android:tint="@color/white"  
         android:layout_gravity="center"
         android:id="@+id/btnSendPicture"
         android:paddingLeft="10sp" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
         android:text="@string/btnSendSnap"
         android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send" 
         android:onClick="sendForm"/>

     </LinearLayout>
```